# Batch - Passing filename with spaces, in for loop search

Tags: batch-file, search, for-loop

Why in seven hells does this work for single word filenames, but not multiple word ones? ...

```
echo.
set /p "file=Please enter the filename, including extension: "
echo.
echo Searching for %file%, please wait...

setlocal 
for %%i in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do ( 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d %%i:\%file% 2^>nul') do (
set "found=%%a" & goto FOUND 
)) 

echo.
echo File not found 
echo.
echo Press any key to exit
pause>nul
goto :EOF

:FOUND
echo.
echo File found in %found% 
for %%A in ("%found%") do (
Set folder=%%~dpA
Set name=%%~nxA
)
cd %folder%
explorer .
echo.
echo Press any key to exit
pause>nul
```

Code has been modified and is derived from various sources online... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Put quotes around `%file%` just like you would any other time you have a filename that can contain spaces?  That's my best guess because I'm not entirely clear on what your input is, what you are expecting to happen, and what is actually happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here (look for a specified file on the root of each drive?), but your problem is with this line:

`for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d %%i:\%file% 2^>nul') do (`

You need to put quotes around: %%i:\%file%

Given a file called `my file.txt`, the output of the `dir` command in the loop will be this:

`dir /b /s /a-d c:\my file.txt 2^>nul`, which is clearly not valid because of the space in the filename.

This would result in your script working:

`for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%%i:\%file%" 2^>nul') do (`

Comment: just needed quotes around %file% as gentleman above pointed out... thanks for your input nevertheless... you get the correct answer mark up! :D